# Autonomous seam detection in Images on matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computational-geometry, image-segmentation

I'm trying to detect seams in welding images for an autonomous welding process.
[image]
I want to find pixel positions of the detected line (the red line in the desired image) in the original image.

I used the following code and finally removed noise from the image to reach the result below.

```
clc,clear,clf;
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcKA.png');
imshow(im);title('Original image'); pause(0.5);
sim = edge(im, 'sobel');
imshow(sim);title('after Sobel'); pause(0.5);
mask = im > 5;
se = strel('square', 5);
mask_s = imerode(mask, se);
mask(mask_s) = false;
mask = imdilate(mask, se);
sim(mask) = false;
imshow(sim);title('after mask');pause(0.5);
sim= medfilt2(sim);
imshow(sim);title('after noise removal')
```

[image]

Unfortunately there is nothing remaining in the image to find the seam perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJcKA.png) Original image.

Comment: any reason why you only have a < 300x300 resolution across your target object? and why does the image look so aweful? is that laser triangulation output or what?
your use of the median filter on a 1-2 pixel line as a last step to remove noise shows that you have absolutely no idea what you are doing. please do yourself a favour get some basic knowledge about image processing befor you go on.

Comment: Do you know the approximate shape of the seam in advance? Or that there is only one seam per image? Or any other helpful constraints?

Comment: @Cecilia  There is only one seam per image.

Comment: @asys +1 for the presentation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your filter more robust to noise. This can be done by giving it a larger support:

```
filter = [ones(2,9);zeros(1,9);-ones(2,9)];
msk = imerode(im > 0, ones(11));  % only object pixels, discarding BG
fim =imfilter(im,filter); 
robust = bwmorph((fim>0.75).*msk,'skel',inf); % get only strong pixels
```

The robust mask looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the seam line is well detected, we just need to pick it as the largest connected component:

```
st = regionprops(bwlabel(robust,8), 'Area', 'PixelList');
[ma mxi] = max([st.Area]); % select the region with the largest area
```

Now we can fit a polygon (2nd degree) to the seem:

```
pp=polyfit(st(mxi).PixelList(:,1), st(mxi).PixelList(:,2), 2);
```

And here it is over the image:

```
imshow(im, 'border','tight');hold on;
xx=1:size(im,2);plot(xx,polyval(pp,xx)+2,'r');
```

[image]

Note the `+2` Y offset due to filter width.

---

PS,
You might find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39191920/1714410) relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Shai gives a great answer, but I wanted to add a bit more context about why your noise filtering doesn't work.

**Why median filtering doesn't work**

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) suggests that median filtering removes noise while preserving edges, which is why you might have chosen to use it. However, in your case it will almost certainly not work, here's why:

Median filtering slides a window across the image. In each area, it replaces the central pixel with the median value from the surrounding window. [`medfilt2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html) uses a 3x3 window by default. Let's look at a 3x3 block near your line,

[image: Location of window]

A 3x3 block around [212 157] looks like this

```
 [0 0 0
  1 1 1
  0 0 0]
```

The median value is 0! So even though we're in the middle of a line segment, the pixel will be filtered out.

**The alternative to median filtering**

Shai's method for removing noise instead finds the largest connected group of pixels and ignores smaller groups of pixels. If you also wanted to remove these small groups from your image, Matlab provides a filter [`bwareaopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html) which removes small objects from binary images.

For example, if you replace your line

```
sim= medfilt2(sim);
```

with

```
sim= bwareaopen(sim, 4);
```

The result is much better

[image: after noise removal]

**Alternative edge detectors**

One last note, Shai uses a horizontal gradient filter to find horizontal edges in your image. It works great because your edge is horizontal. If you edge will not always be horizontal, you might want to use another edge detection method. In your original code, you use Sobel, but Matlab provides many options, all of which perform better if you tune their thresholds. As an example, in the following image, I've highlighted the pixels selected by your code (with bwareaopen modification) using four different edge detectors.

[image: Detector comparison]

Comment: very nice explanation. One note, it is worth while noting the difference between **edge** detection and **ridge** detection. While looking at the original image, the seam is an **edge**, after applying edge detection filter the edge pixels form a **ridge** in the edge map. Therefore, while applying median filter to the original image might reduce noise and enhance the edge, applying median filter to the edge map eliminates **ridges** and makes edge detection much harder.